# how to assert objects are equal using hamcrest

Tags: testing, assert, assertions, hamcrest, rest-assured

I want to write test where it checks if two objects are same. When the assert fails I want to know what fields are same and which are not. I can do assert on each of the field but was wondering if there is a way to compere the objects.

Truck Class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Truck {

    private String model;
    private String make;
    private int year;
    private List<TruckPartsObject> parts;

    public Truck(String model, String make, int year) {
        super();
        this.model = model;
        this.make = make;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public List<TruckPartsObject> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

    public void setParts(List<TruckPartsObject> parts) {
        this.parts = parts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Truck{" + "model='" + model + '\'' + ", make='" + make + '\''
                + ", year=" + year + ", parts=" + parts + '}';
    }

}
```

TruckPartsObject Class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TruckPartsObject {

    private String name;
    private String price;
    private HashMap<String, String> partsHashMap;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getPartsHashMap() {
        return partsHashMap;
    }

    public void setPartsHashMap(HashMap<String, String> partsHashMap) {
        this.partsHashMap = partsHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TruckPartsObject{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", price='"
                + price + '\'' + ", partsHashMap=" + partsHashMap + '}';
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void truckTest () {

    Truck pickupTruck1 = new Truck("Big 10", "Chevy", 1976);
    Truck pickupTruck2 = new Truck("Big 10", "Chevy", 1976);        

    List<TruckPartsObject> parts1 = new ArrayList<TruckPartsObject>();
    TruckPartsObject truckPartsObject1 = new TruckPartsObject();
    truckPartsObject1.setName("part1");
    parts1.add(truckPartsObject1);
    pickupTruck1.setParts(parts1);

    List<TruckPartsObject> parts2 = new ArrayList<TruckPartsObject>();
    TruckPartsObject truckPartsObject2 = new TruckPartsObject();
    truckPartsObject2.setName("part1");
    parts2.add(truckPartsObject2);
    pickupTruck2.setParts(parts2);

    pickupTruck2.setParts(parts2);
    System.out.println(pickupTruck1);
    System.out.println(pickupTruck2);

    //how to assert pickupTruck1 and pickupTruck2 have the same 
}
```

**how to assert pickupTruck1 and pickupTruck2 have the same?**

Comment: Does the `Truck` object intentionally not have an `equals` method, or is it just not displayed here?

Comment: It does not have an equals method. I can add the equals method if that's the right solution. If I do that then I have to also override hasCode() and add logic to check if value is not null and check every single value manually. Also when a test fails the error message that shows actual vs. expected will not be as clear. So was wondering is there a better solution.

Comment: You can use EqualsBuilder, HashCodeBuilder and ToStringBuilder of the Apache commons-lang3 library. This will provide useful error message in case of a failure.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a co-worker for the bellow solution:

Use Shazamcrest (https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest)

**assertThat(pickupTruck1, sameBeanAs(pickupTruck2));**